# Why adding height to floatLayout will make it start adding following blocks from the bottom of the screen?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, kivy

I Have the following code in kivy and I'm wondering why the Float Layout started adding it's children from the bottom up, how can I make it go top down again?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<SweetWidget>:
   size_hint: 1, None
   height: 400
   BoxLayout:
       orientation: 'vertical'
       Button:
           text: "1"
       Button:
           text: "2"
       Button:
           text: "3"
       Button:
           text: "4"
       Button:
           text: "5"
       Button:
           text: "6"
''')

class SweetWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass

runTouchApp(SweetWidget())
```

and then the most weird thing happen if I a pos_hint{'top': 1} in the FloatLayout

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle
import sys

Builder.load_string('''
<SweetWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    size_hint: 1,None
    height: 200
    pos_hint: {'top': 1}
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0,0,1,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        #pos_hint: 
        #    {'top': 1
        #    }
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: "2"
        Button:
            text: "6"
''')

class SweetWidget(FloatLayout):
    def build(self):
        data = sys.stdin.readline()
        print("Counted", len(data), "lines.")
    pass

runTouchApp(SweetWidget())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (0,0) coordinate in Kivy is in the bottom left. Therefore when you made the `height: 400`, it is expected that the `FloatLayout` is going to go down and not up.

In the second example, you set again the `height: 200` of the `FloatLayout`, and push it to the top. However a `FloatLayout` still uses absolute values (you might want to try `RelativeLayout`), so you have to add the `pos` property in order to relocate the `BoxLayout`

Here are two ways of fixing your examples. I the following, I relocated the height to the `Boxlayout` and move it to the top.

```
Builder.load_string('''
<SweetWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0,0,1,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        height: 400
        size_hint: 1, None
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: "1"
        Button:
            text: "2"
        Button:
            text: "3"
        Button:
            text: "4"
        Button:
            text: "5"
        Button:
            text: "6"
''')
```

In this one, I introduce `pos: self.parent.pos`

```
Builder.load_string('''
<SweetWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    size_hint: 1,None
    height: 100
    pos_hint: {'top': 0.8}
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0,0,1,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        #pos_hint: 
        #    {'top': 1
        #    }
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos: self.parent.pos
        Button:
            text: "2"
        Button:
            text: "6"
''')
```